# Does $(\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z})^\times$ contain $0$?

Tags: group-theory

I recently was told that $(\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z})^\times$ is cyclic if $n$ is prime. But then this is impossible if it contains $0$. Hence, does $(\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z})^\times$ contain $0$?

Comment: No, it does not

Comment: $(\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z)^\times$ contains $1, 2, 3, 4$, and is cyclic with either $2$ or $3$ as generator. The group operation is multiplication.

Comment: It only has the multiplicatively invertible elements and zero is not one of those.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful: $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, +)$ is an (additive) abelian group, whose neutral element (or identity element) is the class of $0$; while $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is something slightly different. It indicates the set of invertible elements - with respect to the multiplication - in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Hence $((\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times,\cdot)$ is a (multiplicative) abelian group (in fact a cyclic group if $p$ is prime) whose neutral element is the class of $1$.

So you always have $0\not\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$. In general $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is the set of elements coprime to $n$ (hence if $n$ is prime it is $\{1,...,n-1\}$).

See also the wikipedia page for the [unit set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_%28ring_theory%29).

Comment: You might want to re-word this, it looks like you're saying $\big(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\big)^\times$ is a ring. The point of the question is that it ISN'T a ring, since it doesn't have a zero element!

Comment: right, I edited!